# Using glm for BufferSubData Calculation

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I've scoured the Internet and found many alternatives, but not one works in my code.

I'm trying to use GLM and OpenGL to create a Camera for my Computer Graphics Engine.
cmr is of type Camera

```
cmr->createOrthoCamera(-2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f); //initialize OrthoCamera
cmr->createPersCamera(30.0f, 640.0f / 480.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f); //initialize Pers Matrix
cmr->createViewMatrix(glm::vec3(-7.f,-7.f,-7.f),glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,0.f),glm::vec3(0.f,1.f,0.f)); //initialize View Matrix with lookat
cmr->setUboId(shPrgm->getUniformBlockIndex("SharedMatrices")); //itialize uboId with value from loaded shader
cmr->initCamera(UBO_BP);
cmr->switchProjection(); //just to start one of the vars
```

So i'm starting by allocating space for two mat4 matrices (initCamera):

```
glGenBuffers(1, &uboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboId);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4) * 2, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, UBO_BP, uboId);
```

And then when I call draw I do:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uboId);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4), glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix[0]));
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4), sizeof(glm::mat4), glm::value_ptr(ProjMatrix[0]));
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

But the image is all black. I know the problems are in this zone because if I switch from glm to GLfloat matrixes it works.
The problem must be in the sizeof() or in the draw()..
Can anyone help me?

My Camera definition:

```
#pragma once

#include "Dependencies\glew\glew.h"
#include "Dependencies\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include "Dependencies\glm\glm.hpp"
#include "Dependencies\glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "Dependencies\glm\gtc\type_ptr.hpp"

namespace CGEngine {

class Camera {
private:

    GLuint uboId;

    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix;

    glm::mat4 PersMatrix;
    glm::mat4 OrthoMatrix;

    glm::mat4* ProjMatrix = &OrthoMatrix;

    bool perspective = false;

public:



    Camera();

    void initCamera(GLuint UBO_BP);

    void createOrthoCamera(GLfloat left, GLfloat right, GLfloat bottom, GLfloat top, GLfloat nearZ, GLfloat farZ);
    void createPersCamera(GLfloat flovy, GLfloat aspect, GLfloat nearZ, GLfloat farZ);

    void createViewMatrix(glm::vec3 eye, glm::vec3 center, glm::vec3 up);

    void setUboId(GLuint newUboId);


    void draw();

    void switchProjection();

};
```

}

Comment: `glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix[0])` -> `glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix)`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz changed to that. Still black.

Comment: @user2934164: The problem is likely elsewhere. My first guesses were the shaders where the matrices are used, and the actual glm code creating those matrices. It could be as simple as your previous `GLfloat` based matrices using a different memory layout than glm does (and your shaders assuming that one).